# Find longest sequence of consecutive even and odd place swappable elements in an array

Tags: javascript

I need to find longest consecutive even and odd place swappable elements in an array. Number in the even place are swappable if they are equal and same rule applies for odd place elements.

For e.g. if we have an array `[1,4,8,2,4,2,4,9,16]` here element at position 3rd and 5th is 2 so it is equal so they are swappable and elements at position 4th and 6th is 4 so it is also equal then the longest consecutive swappable sequence is `[2,4,2,4]`

if we consider array `[5,7,3,9,5,1,5,7,1,5,1,5]` then longest consecutive swappable sequence is `[1,5,1,5]`

I am trying to solve this is creating array for even and odd place elements and then trying to compare if they are consecutive sequence.

```
var Arr1 = [1,2,1,4,1,2,15,18],
evenArr = [],
oddArr = [], mergedArr=[];

if(Arr1.length > 2) {
    for (var i=0;i<Arr1.length;i++){
        if ((i+2)%2==0) {
            evenArr.push(Arr1[i]);
        }
        else {
            oddArr.push(Arr1[i]);
        }
    }

    let evenSeq = [];
    let oddSeq = []; 
    let k=0; 
    let z=0;

    for (var j=k;j < evenArr.length;j++){

        if (evenArr[k] === evenArr[j]) {
            evenSeq.push(evenArr[j]);
        }
        else {
            k = j+1; 
            for (m=z; m<evenSeq.length;m++){
            console.log('K in odd: ', k);

            if (oddArr[z] === oddArr[m]) {
                oddSeq.push(oddArr[m]);
            }
            else {
                z = m+1;
                break;
            }
        }
        }


    }

    for (c=0; c<evenSeq.length;c++){
        mergedArr.push(evenSeq[c]);
        if(oddSeq[c]){
           mergedArr.push(oddSeq[c]);
        } else {
           break;
        }
    }
    console.log('mergedArr: ', mergedArr);
} else{
    mergedArr = Arr1;
}
console.log('mergedArr: ', mergedArr);
```

Comment: i have seen this type og question before, what means *"swappable"*? what are other sequences in the array?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please let me know if its clear